# Proving that one typeclass is a subset of another in Scala

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, typeclass, abstraction

Say I have the following two typeclasses:

```
object Foo {
   sealed trait FooClass[A]
   implicit object FooString extends FooClass[String]
   implicit object FooInt extends FooClass[Int]       
}

object Bar {
  trait BarClass[A] //leave this one unsealed as we're attempting to prove that Foo is a subset of Bar, not the other way around.
  implicit object BarString extends BarClass[String]
  implicit object BarInt extends BarClass[Int]
  implicit object BarDouble extends BarClass[Double]
}
```

is it possible to provide a hint to the compiler that Foo is a subset of Bar somehow, such that the following would compile, without a change to the type signatures of either method?

```
class Outer(callee : Inner) {
  import Foo._
  def call[A : FooClass](a) : Unit = callee.call(a);
}

class Inner
  import Bar._
  def call[B : BarClass](b) : Unit = ();
}

val test = new Outer(new Inner)
test.call(123)
test.call("Hello World")
```

My main objective is to allow the `Outer` class to be entirely unaware of the existence of the `BarClass` typeclass - using the `Inner` class to abstract over it entirely. Is this possible? For those who are interested, there's some context over in [this git repository](https://github.com/timcowlishaw/scala-typeclass-experiments/commits/master) - the commit descriptions have some more detailed exposition of the problem I'm trying to solve).

Comment: Can't you just make `FooClass` extend `BarClass`? Or failing that, declare an implicit conversion from one to the other?

Comment: Aha, good question - The context for this question is the need to abstract over typeclasses defined in 3rd party libraries - in this example, `Bar` would be defined by the library, while the other classes would be defined by my client code. I'm trying to insulate `Foo` and `Outer` from `Bar` entirely, with `Inner` acting as an adaptor between the two, so wanted to avoid extending BarClass.

Comment: An implicit conversion, however, might be exactly what I need, although I'm having trouble understanding how it'd work. Would an identity function with a specific signature be sufficient? something like `implicit def foo2bar[F : FooClass, B : BarClass](f : F) : B = f`?

Comment: I meant something like `implicit def fooClassAsBarClass[F](implicit fc: FooClass[F]): BarClass[F] = new BarClass[F]{}`. That will make an implicit `BarClass` available for anything that has an implicit `FooClass`, though you may have to be careful with implicit precedence to avoid conflicting with a "real" `BarClass` for the same type.

Comment: Aaah sorry, that's not quite what I mean, either - I'm thinking about the case where the set of types which are instances of class `Foo` (which is fixed as the trait is sealed) is a subset of the set of types which are instances of class `Bar` which are already defined elsewhere - as 'real' instances in your terms. In that case, for any type `X` for which an instance `Foo[X]` exists, then there is a corresponding real instance of `Bar[X]` defined, but I can't find a way of stating this that the compiler can understand.

Comment: Well, you could write that implicit function, and just map to the already-existent instance of `BarClass[F]` - by matching the individual cases if necessary, or using reflection. I mean, fundamentally you're going to have to either require the caller to supply a `BarClass` (which will always be there, but the compiler doesn't know that), or tell the compiler a way that it can always get a `BarClass`

Comment: Aha, yes, thanks, I think I'm now very nearly there - see my implementation of `BarAdaptor` here: https://gist.github.com/timcowlishaw/c5c618044344db8ef9d5. However, this still doesn't quite compile (see https://gist.github.com/timcowlishaw/1ea82c0286eb182fb168) - it seems that an explicit reference to `BarString` / `BarInt` doesn't have type `Bar[A]` (for some `A : Foo`). Perhaps I'm missing a variance annotation?

Comment: So, I eventually solved my original problem (of abstracting over a typeclass defined by a 3rd party library) by taking a slightly different approach, which obviated the need for this mapping at all! for the interested: https://gist.github.com/timcowlishaw/213c1363de845fe34bad